# Bandwidth throttling while copying files between computers

Tags: c#, file-copying, bandwidth-throttling

I've been trying to make a program to transfer a file with bandwidth throttling (after zipping it) to another computer on the same network.

I need to get its bandwidth throttled in order to avoid saturation (Kind of the way Robocopy does).

Recently, I found the `ThrottledStream` class, but It doesn't seem to be working, since I can send a 9MB with a limitation of 1 byte throttling and it still arrives almost instantly, so I need to know if there's some misapplication of the class.

Here's the code:

```
using (FileStream originStream = inFile.OpenRead())    
using (MemoryStream compressedFile = new MemoryStream())      
using (GZipStream zippingStream = new GZipStream(compressedFile, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    originStream.CopyTo(zippingStream); 
    using (FileStream finalDestination = File.Create(destination.FullName + "\\" + inFile.Name + ".gz"))
    {
        ThrottledStream destinationStream = new ThrottledStream(finalDestination, bpsLimit);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int readCount = compressedFile.Read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
        while(readCount > 0)
        {
            destinationStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            readCount = compressedFile.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you find this `ThrottledStream`? It's not in the standard library..

Comment: It's not a standar library. Found it right here. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18243/Bandwidth-throttling

Comment: I've checked the `ThrottledStream` code... looks like it might work as advertised, but I can see a couple potential problems with it.  Most importantly though, how many bytes are actually being written to it, and how many at a time?  To me it appears that `ThrottledStream` simply delays each write operation *after the first*.  If all of your data is written in the first write, it goes through immediately.  *Subsequent* writes are delayed, but each write is sent in one burst after a delay.

Answer (score 1):

The `ThrottledStream` class you linked to uses a delay calculation to determine how long to wait before perform the current write.  This delay is based on the amount of data sent **before the current write**, and how much time has elapsed.  Once the delay period has passed it writes the entire buffer in a single chunk.

The problem with this is that it doesn't do any checks on the size of the buffer being written in a particular write operation.  If you ask it to limit throughput to 1 byte per second, then call the `Write` method with a 20MB buffer, it will write the entire 20MB immediately.  If you then try to write another block of data that is 2 bytes long, it will wait for a very long time (20*2^20 seconds) before writing those two bytes.

In order to get the `ThrottledStream` class to work more smoothly, you have to call `Write` with very small blocks of data.  Each block will still be written immediately, but the delays between the write operations will be smaller and the throughput will be much more even.

In your code you use a variable named `bufferSize` to determine the number of bytes to process per read/write in the internal loop.  Try setting `bufferSize` to 256, which will result in many more reads and writes, but will give the `ThrottledStream` a chance to actually introduce some delays.

If you set `bufferSize` to be the same as `bpsLimit` you should see a single write operation complete every second.  The smaller you set `bufferSize` the more write operations you'll get per second, the *smoother* the bandwidth throttling will work.

Normally we like to process as much of a buffer as possible in each operation to decrease the overheads, but in this case you're explicitly trying to add overheads to slow things down :)

Comment: Thanks. It worked! :). I also changed the copy code with a CopyTo and now it transfers with the appropiate throttling.

Comment: I also found out that the throttling process doesn't always work as desired, because from time to time (not regularly) the stream skips the throttling.

Comment: @FranciscoPalma Glad you got it working.  I'm mildly surprised that CopyTo works... will have to look into how it is writing the data to see if it's using small blocks, since that could lead to a fairly large overhead on some operations.  Good to know anyway.